# Update batch codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to update the database by editing a form with multiple valuse based on 1 id.

I'm trying to use $this->db->update_batch('table', $data, 'id');

But i think i'm not getting the correct parse to insert the data in batch mode to the database.

My question is if this way is the correct:

```
<input type="text" name="item_id[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="rep_id[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="ean[]" value="">


$update_item_id     = $this->input->post('item_id');
$update_rep_id      = $this->input->post('rep_id');      
$update_ean         = $this->input->post('ean');

$update_items = array(
                'id'        =>  $update_item_id,
                'rep_id'    =>  $update_rep_id,
                'ean'       =>  $update_ean
);

if($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->model_m->editbatch($rep_id, $update_items)){

this->session->set_flashdata('message', "All is ok");
            redirect("controller", 'refresh');
```

}

Model:

```
public function editbatch($id, $update_items)
{
    $this->db->update('table', $update_items, 'id');
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you don't use correctly the update, try like this:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: don't forget to load the database: $this->load->database(); and add a return = true to your model function

Comment: The result is: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `mytable` SET `item_id` = Array, `rep_id` = Array, `ean` = Array WHERE `rep_id` = '1'

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_batch` instead of `update`

```
public function editbatch($id, $update_items)
{
    $this->db->update_batch('table', $update_items, 'id');
}
```